# radio button doesn't work in a jquery popup box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I want to create a jquery fullscreen popup and put a radio button in it.

I have a code that works fine but not for that radio button!

please check my code here [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/phpmLqu1/5/)

The popup window works great but after first click on a radio button,all radio buttons will be locked.
Can sb tell me about this problem?
tnx

html code:

```
<div class="button"><a href="#">
 <img class="btn-open" src="http://ec.l.thumbs.canstockphoto.com/canstock13758850.jpg" alt="">
 <img class="btn-close" src="http://ec.l.thumbs.canstockphoto.com/canstock13758850.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>

 <div class="overlay">
 <div class="wrap">
 <ul class="wrap-nav">
 <li>
     <h2> hello everyone!</h2>

 </li>
 </ul>
 <div class="social">
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/phpmLqu1/6/

Change your code from return false to e.stopPropagation like this

```
$('.wrap').on('click', function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```